# 256 possible values in a 8 bits

Tags: memory, ram

I am confused when I read the details section that says `1 byte` which is `8 bits` gives us a potential of 2^8 or 256 possible values. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_computing)

If i am doing the math correctly

```
2^0 = 1
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
2^3 = 8
2^4 = 16
2^5 = 32
2^6 = 64
2^7 = 128

Total = 255
```

The way i see it there is total or possible 255 values.

Comment: You forgot zero `0`

Comment: am i not including 0 when i do 2^0

Comment: That's precisely your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is also a value so for 8 bits, the value range is 0-255.

`00000000` is the lowest and `11111111` (255) is the highest.

2^x gives you the total number of possible values for x bits. You should be using 2^x to get the number of possible combinations only where x > 0. If x = 0, it points to a no-bit scenario which is irrelevant.

For your case, it is not correct to sum values from 2^0 to 2^7. The correct approach should be just calculating 2^8, which is 256.

Comment: am i not including 0 when i do 2^0

Comment: Actually no, 2^0 gives the number of possible alternative states when there are no bits (0 bits). It does not make sense from a computing perspective but from a mathmetical perspective it points to a single state with no alternatives, so it is 1. 2^1=2 so with a single bit you can have 2 states, 0 and 1 .... so on.